# how to check that a field in mysql contains a specific word

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check if a field in mysql contains a specific word using select query

exmaple: field 'name' = test1,test2,test3

```
Select * from table where name Like '%test3%
```

it returns empty, any help

Answer (score 2):

use [find_in_set()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * from `table` where FIND_IN_SET(name, 'test1,test2,test3 ');
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to find word like test1,test2 etc

```
Select * from table where name Like '%test%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN ( 'test1',' test2', 'test3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Add single quotes after `'%test3%`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%test3%
```